# git: merging local branch into divergent upstream/master

Tags: git, github

So I have a locally cloned repository to which I've made some changes in a new branch while maintaining the master branch from upstream. My modifications to an earlier commit of the master branch are now divergent since a lot of the master branch has changed substantially. One file in particular, to which I've made several alterations has been split into three in the upstream and I'd like to merge my edits into one of these. But since the new files are named quite differently from what they were earlier, I fear a lot of complications arising with a generic merge (see below on what I mean by this); generating a diff/patch also wouldn't work for the same reasons. How could I bring my branch to converge with the upstream?

For reference, my branch in on https://github.com/brihadeesh/elegant-emacs/tree/dev
As you perhaps will notice in the master branch, `elegance.el` (although it's still around) was split into two theme files and what is now `elegant.el` and for my branch to be even with master (with the exception of some additional files I've added), I'll have to merge my changes from `dev/elegance.el` into `master/elegant.el`, while accomodating the changes from upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thinking and might have figured out a way to do this.

1. I first add the new file `elegant.el` to my branch by running from my branch:

```
git checkout master elegant.el
```

2. Generate a diff with my version of `elegance.el` against `elegant.el` (since both of them technically have the same structure) and then patch each diff-chunk manually so as to verify none of the chunks adds previously deleted bits of code.
3. Check and merge into master for my use and perhaps set up a different branch to fetch/merge upstream/master commits.

Could anyone verify this while I try it out?